# Parsing string in Pandas

Tags: pandas, string, parsing

I am working on a dataframe with one of the columns with values like this -

| field |
| --- |
| marketable_email_status_m10 |
| email_availability_status_m11 |
| ending_ar_60_to_89_dpd_m11 |
| email_availability_status_m1 |

I want my final output such that the string is split in two columns as below:

| field | text1 | text2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| marketable_email_status_m10 | marketable_email_status | m10 |
| email_availability_status_m11 | email_availability_status | m11 |
| ending_ar_60_to_89_dpd_m11 | ending_ar_60_to_89_dpd | m11 |
| email_availability_status_m1 | email_availability_status | m1 |

I have been able to yield column 3, but not sure how to go about column 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.rsplit`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rsplit.html) with `n=1` for split by last `_`:

```
df[['text1','text2']] = df['field'].str.rsplit('_', n=1, expand=True)
print (df)
                           field                      text1 text2
0    marketable_email_status_m10    marketable_email_status   m10
1  email_availability_status_m11  email_availability_status   m11
2     ending_ar_60_to_89_dpd_m11     ending_ar_60_to_89_dpd   m11
3   email_availability_status_m1  email_availability_status    m1
```

Answer (score 3):

With [`extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) function please try following.

```
df[["text1","text2"]] = df['field'].str.extract(r'^(.*)_(.*)$')
```

***Explanation:***

- Applying `df.str.extract` function on DataFrame's `field` column.
- Then using 2 capturing groups to create 2 new columns in DataFrame, named `text1` and `text2`.
- First capturing group has everything till `_` and 2nd one has rest of the value(as per OP's requirement).
- Saving value of created capturing groups into fields named `text1` and `text2`.

Output will be as follows:

```
    field                           text1                       text2
0   marketable_email_status_m10     marketable_email_status     m10
1   email_availability_status_m11   email_availability_status   m11
2   ending_ar_60_to_89_dpd_m11      ending_ar_60_to_89_dpd      m11
3   email_availability_status_m1    email_availability_status   m1
```